# Slow iterating thru Outlook.Items to find contacts

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am having an issue where I am trying to find at least one contact inside any of the outlook folders. I have a recursive function that iterates thru the items inside a folder and if the item is of type contact then we add it to a list. However, this code runs extremely slow when folders have a large number of records say 4000 items.

Is there any way just to get contacts or is there a way to make this code more efficient?

```
foreach (var item in folderBase.Items)
{
    if (returnFirst && result.Count > 0)
        break;

    if ((item is Outlook.ContactItem))
    {
        result.Add((Outlook.ContactItem)item);
    }
}
```

Comment: A sample code is posted @ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702626/vsto-outlook-contact-iteration-is-so-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702626/vsto-outlook-contact-iteration-is-so-slow)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, storing 4000 live Outlook objects in a list is a bad idea: you will run out of RPC channels in case of online Exchange store at item 255. Store the entry ids and use them to call Namespace.GetItemFromID() when you actuqlly need it; then release it as soon as you are done.

Secondly, use [MAPIFolder.GetTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.gettable.aspx) - it will let you retrieve values from multiple items without actually opening them; perfect in your case. Try something like the following (VB script):

```
set Folder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set Table = Folder.GetTable("[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Contact' ")
Table.Columns.Add("EntryID")
while not Table.EndOfTable
  set Row = Table.GetNextRow()
  vEntryId = Row.Item(1)
  Debug.Print vEntryId
wend
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know how it goes thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class instead.

Read more about these methods and see the sample code in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)

You can use the [MessageClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863901(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items to get the contact items only.